# re.split with spaces in python

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string of text that looks like this:

```
'                     19,301         14,856        18,554'
```

Where   is a space.

I'm trying to split it on the white space, but I need to retain all of the white space as an item in the new list. Like this:

```
['                     ', '19,301','        ', '14,856', '        ', '18,554']
```

I have been using the following code:

```
re.split(r'( +)(?=[0-9])', item)
```

and it returns:

```
['', '                     ', '19,301', '        ', '14,856', '        ', '18,554']
```

Notice that it always **adds an empty element to the beginning of my list**.  It's easy enough to drop it, but I'm really looking to understand what is going on here, so I can get the code to treat things consistently.  Thanks.

Comment: imho, using `\s` makes it **less** clear and just annoying if anyone here wanted to actually try it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann agreed. this is harder to try to deal with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `re.split` method, if the capture group is matched at the start of a string, the "[result will start with an empty string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)". The reason for this is so that `join` method can behave as the inverse of the `split` method.

It might not make a lot of sense for your case, where the separator matches are of varying sizes, but if you think about the case where the separators were a `|` character and you wanted to perform a join on them, with the extra empty string it would work:

```
>> item = '|19,301|14,856|18,554'
>> items = re.split(r'\|', item)
>> print items
['', '19,301', '14,856', '18,554']
>> '|'.join(items)
'|19,301|14,856|18,554'
```

But without it, the initial pipe would be missing:

```
>> items = ['19,301', '14,856', '18,554']
>> '|'.join(items)
'19,301|14,856|18,554'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `re.findall()`:

```
>>> s = '\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s19,301\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s14,856\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s18,554'.replace('\\s',' ')
>>> re.findall(r' +|[^ ]+', s)
['                     ', '19,301', '         ', '14,856', '        ', '18,554']
```

You said "space" in the question, so the pattern works with space. For matching runs of any whitespace character you can use:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\s+|\S+', s)
['                     ', '19,301', '         ', '14,856', '        ', '18,554']
```

The pattern matches one or more whitespace characters *or* one or more non-whitespace character, for example:

```
>>> s='  \t\t  ab\ncd\tef   g '
>>> re.findall(r'\s+|\S+', s)
['  \t\t  ', 'ab', '\n', 'cd', '\t', 'ef', '   ', 'g', ' ']
```