# Why are there space outcome in my re.split() result

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, python-re

I want to extract the strings in the brackets and single quote in the given a string, e.g. Given **['this']**, extract **this**
, yet it keeps haunting me that the following example and result:

```
import re 
target_string = "['this']['current']"
result = re.split(r'[\[|\]|\']+', target_string)
print(result)
```

I got

```
['', 'this', 'current', '']
# I expect ['this', 'current']
```

Now I really don't understand where are the first and last **' '** in the result coming from, I guarantee that the input target_string has no such leading and trailing space, I don't expect that they occurred in the result

Can anybody help me fix this, please?

Comment: Mostly explained here: [re.split with spaces in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005907/re-split-with-spaces-in-python).

Comment: It's not a space, but an empty string.  When you split on [ there is nothing to the left of the first [ in your string so you get an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using re.split match every time the pattern is found and since your string starts and ends with the pattern is output a `''` at he beguining and end to be able to use join on the output and form the original string

If you want to capture why don't you use re.findall instead of re.split? you have very simple use if you **only have one word** per bracket.

```py
target_string = "['this']['current']"
re.findall("\w", target_string)
```

output

```
['this', 'current']
```

**Note the above will not work for**:

`['this is the', 'current']`

For such a case you can use lookahead `(?=...)` and lookbehind `(?<=...)` and capture everything in a nongreedy way `.+?`

```py
target_string = "['this is the', 'current']"
re.findall("(?<=\[\').+?(?=\'\])", target_string) # this patter is equivalent "\[\'(.+)\'\]"
```

output:

```
['this is the', 'current']
```